# How to save output graph of "dtreeviz.trees" dtreeviz on local HHD

Tags: python, visualization, graphviz, decision-tree, dtreeviz

Following is my code:

```
from sklearn import tree
from dtreeviz.trees import dtreeviz # will be used for tree visualization
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import graphviz

ax2 = dtreeviz(
 RFC1.estimators_[0],
 X_train1, y_train1, target_name='Mask',
 scale=1.1, class_names=['0','1'])
ax2
```

As I am working on jupyter notebook so I can see the graph as soon as I run `ax2`. I want to save this output to on my local system in PNG format BUT I can find a way to do this!

Answer (score 1):

Now its works different

[Here](https://github.com/parrt/dtreeviz/blob/master/README.md) is tutorial

It looks like:

```
import dtreeviz
viz_model = dtreeviz.model(clf,
                       X_train=X, y_train=y,
                       feature_names=iris.feature_names,
                       target_name='iris',
                       class_names=iris.target_names)

v = viz_model.view()     # render as SVG into internal object 
v.show()                 # pop up window
v.save("/tmp/iris.svg")  # optionally save as svg
```

Answer (score 0):

You can save it to svg format.

```html
viz = dtreeviz(spark_dtree)

viz.save("/path/dtreeviz.svg")
```